# how can i sum all values depend on index value in pandas?

Tags: python, indexing, sum

I want to calculate some values between type1 and type2 elements. For example if have index like: `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` then it will equals to `(a,b)+(b,a)` I want to sum values if reverse indexes exists.

[image: Table screenshot]

Comment: What if the reverse index does not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `frozenset`:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['total'].groupby(df[['type1', 'type2']].apply(frozenset, 1)).sum()
```

Output:

```
(b, a)    15
(c, a)    19
Name: total, dtype: int64
```

Comment: nice. maybe you could assign your result to a `new_df` and restore the multiindex like: `new_df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(x) for x in list(new_df.index)], names=['type1', 'type2'])`

Answer (score 0):

Let `df` be your DataFrame. Swap the first and second levels of the MultiIndex, concatenate the original and the new DataFrames, and calculate row sums:

```
pd.concat([df, df.swaplevel()], axis=1).sum(1)
#a  b    15
#   c    19
#b  a    15
#c  a    19
```

The solution works even for the rows that do not have matching reversed rows. The answer has duplicated rows for the direct and the reversed index. You will have to filter out the unwanted rows.